# getFragment from a dynamic component in Relay

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, graphql

My use case is that I have a Node application that consumes data from a CMS, and in that CMS I give the users the ability to select a React Component as a "Layout". I'd like for Relay to be able to get a GraphQL Fragment from that dynamically select component. When the Layout's parent component mounts, it goes through its query and gets the layout component it needs and sets a Relay variable - it then needs to get a fragment from that component. Is there a way to do that?

Here is the parent level query:

```js
export default Relay.createContainer(WordpressPage, {

initialVariables:{
    Component: null,
    page: null,
    showPosts: false,
    limit: 5
},

prepareVariables(prevVars){
    return{
        ...prevVars,
        showPosts: true
    }
},

fragments: {
  viewer: ({Component, showPosts, limit}) => Relay.QL`
    fragment on User {
      ${PostList.getFragment("viewer", {limit:limit}).if(showPosts)},
        page(post_name:$page){
          id,
          post_title,
          post_type,
          post_content,
          thumbnail,
          layout{
           meta_value
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

As you can see, it queries and gets a layout field. When it mounts, it sets the Relay Component variable to be a React Component. Instead of "PostList.getFragment", I'd really like to be able to do a Component.getFragment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you must do here is to interpolate *all possible fragment references* into the query. Starting with Relay v0.7.1 you will be able to interpolate into your query an *array* of fragment references:

```js
const COMPONENTS = [
  [PostList, 'showPosts'],
  [OtherKindOfList, 'showOthers'],
  /* ... */
];

static initialVariables = {
  showPosts: false,
  showOthers: false,
  /* ... */
};

fragments: {
  viewer: variables => Relay.QL`
    fragment on User {
      ${COMPONENTS.map(([Component, variableName]) => {
        const condition = variables[variableName];
        return Component
          .getFragment('viewer', {limit: variables.limit})
          .if(condition);
      })},
      # ...
    `,
  },
});
```

**Warning**: Presently there is a limitation in Relay that requires that the interpolated expression return either:

- a fragment reference

  `${Foo.getFragment('viewer')}`
- an array of fragment references

  `${COMPONENTS.map(c => c.getFragment('viewer'))}`
- a route-conditional function that returns exactly *one* fragment reference

  `${(route) => COMPONENTS[route].getFragment('viewer')}`

The original poster's use case was for a route-conditional function that returns an *array* of fragment references, which is not yet supported. See the comments for more information. See also [facebook/relay/issues/896](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/896)

Comment: Thanks! Any idea when 0.7.1 will be released?

Comment: I released v0.7.1 a moment ago, just for you. :)

Comment: Will the condition only work for boolean variables? I couldn't set a 'Layout' variable and check that it equals a string?

Comment: I don't think so, because `condition` here represents a ‘variable’ data type, and not actually a raw boolean. This lets Relay evaluate the variable over time to see if the `if()` condition passes or fails.

Comment: I'm still getting a "Expected prop `viewer` supplied to `PostList` to be data fetched by Relay." The query runs, gets the layout, then reruns, but before it reruns I think PostList gets rendered. I need to only render PostList after it's gotten the fragment from PostList. Thoughts?

Comment: What happens if you check to see if `viewer` is null before rendering `PostList`? `render() { return this.props.viewer == null ? null : <PostList viewer={this.props.viewer} />; }`

Comment: No dice - it just doesn't render anything and I still get the "expected prop viewer" error

Comment: Strange. Are you able to share more of the code, particularly the implementations of `PostList` and `WordpressPage`?

Comment: Here is [page](https://github.com/ramsaylanier/WordPressExpress/blob/layouts/app/components/pages/page.js)


Here is [PostList](https://github.com/ramsaylanier/WordPressExpress/blob/layouts/app/components/posts/PostList.js)

Comment: Thank you for doing that. I was able to spot the problem right away. I'll update the answer in a bit, but in the meantime take a look at this fix. Basically you have to move all of your variable wrangling into `prepareVariables()`; a Relay variable is not a boolean, so you can't do things like `if(variables.foo) { … }` in your interpolation. https://gist.github.com/steveluscher/3681d7795fbd2f13141b

Comment: Still nope. The mapping only runs before the component mounts. When the variables update the map doesnt rerun. Verrified that the variables are getting update properly though - I feel like this is sooooo close.

Comment: The mapping shouldn't need to re-run, since now you've primed the `if(…)` calls with the right variable for each fragment. When the variables change, the `if(…)` should be reevaluated with the new variable value. Despite the `map(…)` not re-running, what behavior are you seeing or not seeing now?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error that PostList is expecting viewer to be Relay data. Same error as before.

Comment: Also, if I console.log(this.props.viewer) from Page render, I don't even see a   RelayFragmentPointer. If, for example, I set showPosts to true in initial variables, everything runs fine and I see the RelayFragmentPointer.

Comment: Sorry, one last thing - if I remove the map and try to us PostList by itself with the condition - it still doesn't work unless I initially set showPosts to true.

Comment: I'm stumped! I drummed up a Relay Playground that tries to get as close to your implementation as possible. Can you take a look at this, and see if you can get it into a state where it repros the problem? http://tinyurl.com/zvq3a3z

Comment: Will do. In the meantime my solution has to remove the condition from the map function and pass a boolean to the child component, then adding a condition to each child component query. It works but I end up with empty fragments.